# "You can't find a shorty to troop your bid with you; hit with a two to four is difficult."

Tags: meaning-in-context, lyrics

The rap group "Mobb Deep" from New York City — the song "[Survival of the Fittest](https://genius.com/Mobb-deep-survival-of-the-fittest-lyrics)" (1995):

> I live a world where squads hit the block hard
> Ask my man Twin when he got bagged
> That fucked me up, God, but shit happens for a reason
> You find out who's your true peoples
> When you're upstate bleeding
> You can't find a **shorty** to **troop** your **bid** with you
> **Hit with** a two to four is difficult
> Wild on the streets, I try to maintain

What does "shorty" mean here?
What does "troop" mean here?
What does "bid" mean here?
What does "hit with" mean here?

Thanks.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is asking us to guess the meaning of 'rap' lyrics, which are not standard English.

Comment: @LukeSawczak That should probably be an answer (although I think *bid* can only mean "prison sentence" in this context).

Comment: I think non-standard English is very interesting, innit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "shorty" is a girl(friend). "Trooping" means walking (alongside?). A "two-to-four" is probably a prison sentence of two to four years. "Hit with" means having something unexpectedly given to you or done to you.

A "bid" could be time with a girl / a date, but it could also be a prison sentence.

Hence, this probably means:

> You can't find a girlfriend to stick with you during your prison sentence. It's hard being given a sentence of two to four years.

As Michael said in a comment, this is very specific to rap. But given the popularity of rap and the ease with which the language spreads on Tiktok, it's fairly easy to hear this if you hang around teenagers (as I do in my role as high school teacher).

Comment: Well done. What's funny is that they did not ask what upstate means. If you are from NYC, go upstate is what people say for anything north of NYC. Here. prison. The long-terms ones are outside the city.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Although mentioning the user "Michael" in it seems inappropriate to me because he wanted to close this thread. That is, he wanted other users (including you) to be not able to answer this question.